# How can I initialize multiple hashmaps at once

Tags: java, hashmap, initialization, repeat

so I have all this hashmaps that I have created, and I wonder if there was a way to initialize all of them at once (because "never repeat yourself")

```
Map<Integer, String> inter = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> join = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> diff = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> diff2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Also what about expertions like this:(sc1 and sc2 are a scanner)

```
sc1.nextLine(); 
sc2.nextLine();
```

Comment: There's a limit to _"never repeat yourself"_.

Comment: I'm not sure what the additional question is asking about it seems entirely unrelated.

Comment: Look's OK to me. Java isn't expressive enough to shorten that without more work than it's worth - [re]assignment to N variables makes the exact example pretty much unfeasible. In any case, the general way to "do N at once" is to use a collection and some form of iteration.